How do you stop water from going into your underwater base?
When I dig down far enough right next to the water, and I go out to build a glass dome so I can see inside, the water would come in.
I tried a second layer and sponges but they didn't work.

Is this in survival mode or creative?

Got a picture of the place you're trying to build it?

Here's two ways you can try:

Build your dome with the water first. Don't try to clear out the water as it'll be futile while your structure is not built. Then, fill the whole thing with sand (or another easy to dig block such as dirt) and dig it out.
Build your dome first, then segment chambers about 8 blocks wide. You can then easily clear the water out using sponge blocks (these can be found in Ocean Monuments) from top to bottom.

It is important to destroy your clearing blocks (sponges or clay/sand/dirt) from top to bottom as the water above it will create source blocks underneath because it is bordering at least two source blocks as it spreads.
If you need to stop water from coming in an entrance, you can use a "solid" transparent block such as wall signs (standing signs can be destroyed by water) or ladders to block your entrances that border water.
